# When fire shopify app deploy cmd got the error?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-cli

I have an old app of Shopify made with Laravel (without using CLI). now I am trying to create theme app extension for that I do the following things

Step-1

```
shopify app generate extension
```

It creates the extension directory and some necessary files and folders under the extension directory. now I need to deploy the extension code so I fire below command

Step - 2

```
shopify app deploy
```

and now I got the following error

[image]

I am using Shopify CLI 3.45
Node version is 18^
and ruby 3.2.0
all latest version

Comment: Do you have Bundler 2.3.8 or higher?

Comment: Yes I have @TwistedOwl

Comment: That's odd, I'm afraid you will have to post it as an issue in CLI repository as this looks like a bug not a problem with your project

Answer (score 1):

Updating to [CLI version 3.46](https://github.com/Shopify/cli/releases/tag/3.46.0) might fix the issue as well.

There was a similar [issue](https://github.com/Shopify/cli/issues/1971) about deploys failing yesterday, which looks like the update fixed.

Comment: I am also doing this however not get the solution and still got the same error

Comment: Are you using a ruby environment manager? It could be that theme-check is available to another version of Ruby than one the CLI is trying to deploy with.

There's some more troubleshooting outlined in [this comment](https://github.com/Shopify/cli/issues/150#issuecomment-1185650167), but if that doesn't work then you should create a new issue.